# Is there a way to use something like IN for a CAML query?

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I'd like to query a list using multiple ids at the same time. In straight SQL, I could just use IN(ID1, ID2, ID3). Is there any way to do this within a CAML query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is [In Element (Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625761.aspx).

```
<In>
  <FieldRef Name = "Field_Name"/>
  <Values>    <Value Type = "Field_Type"/>
  </Values>  <XML />
</In>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know why I couldn't find that when I tried searching. Probably because "In" is too common of a word. In any case, thanks a bunch for this.